# [:== :Unexpected operator, too many argument, binary operator expected

Tags: linux, bash

See below:

```
1. 
if [ $var1 == "result" ]
2,3. 
if [ -z $var ]
```

I met this warning in bash version 4.4
Does anyone know this? Please explain detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the fact your `$var` contains spaces. So, those spaces are going to appear in the if, like if they were separating parameters/values. To solve, use `"$var"`, where all spaces are joined into a unique value.

So, if `var1` was bound to `foo bar` in the shell,  in `[ $var1 = "result" ]` the inside of the [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) is expanded as 4 arguments:  `foo`, `bar`, `=`, `result`   but `=` is binary and wants only one argument on each side (so you've got an error like "too many arguments" or "binary operator expected")

Comment: Thank you samthegolden. Can you explain error "binary operator expected"?

Comment: this explains the "binary operator expected". The `$var` with spaces is expanded as *several* arguments.

Comment: Is the same problem, you are sending too much parameters and it only requires 2.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
"$var1" == "result"
```

And:

```
-z "$var1"
```

When $var1 is non existent the tests do not work, that is easily fixed by surrounding the tested variables with "" so that if they are non existent you compare to the empty variable

Comment: I think the problem is that the variables contain spaces, but quoting them solves that as well.

Comment: Also, inside `[ ]` it's best to use `=` instead of `==`. Double-equal in this context is a bashism. If you're trying to be portable, use single-equal; if you're not trying to be portable, use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`, since its syntax is significantly cleaner.

Comment: Thank guys. The last I want to ask you is: why bash print binary operator expected. Can you describe more it detail about that error? Thanks